# Using AJAX and PHP to change combobox choices

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, combobox

I've been trying and struggling all morning to get my combobox to update properly. Once a user selects and option in the first box I want to then populate a second box with options applicable to the first option chosen. I have written a separate php script to take in the option chosen and pull from the sql database the applicable return. This script works fine when run by itself but I cannot get it working within the javascript using AJAX

PHP:

```
<?php
$name=$_GET['name'];

// select box option tag
$selectBoxOption1 = ''; 

// connect mysql server
$con=mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$con) { 
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
}
mysql_select_db('mysql',$con);
$sql1 = "SELECT DISTINCT bike_type FROM bc_fit WHERE name='$name'";
$result1 = mysql_query($sql1);

// play with return result array 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){   
    $selectBoxOption1 .="<option value = '".$row['bike_type']."'>".$row['bike_type']."</option>"; 
}
// return options
echo $selectBoxOption1;
?>
```

Javascript (#nap2 is the current box and #nap 4 the next):

```
$("#nap2").change(function(event){
    var selected = $(this).find('option:selected').text()
    $('#nap4').removeAttr('disabled');
    $('#nap4').empty();
    //need to get options based upon nap 2 choice by calling php script with selected and returning all unqiue bike under that name

    var options4;
    $.ajax({ 
    type: "GET",
    url: 'getbiketype.php', 
    data: "name"=selected,
    success:  function(data) {
      options4 = data;
    }
    });
    $('#nap4').append($(options4));
});
```

Comment: Try getting the `val()` instead of `text()`. `var selected = $(this).find('option:selected').val();` Also maybe posting your form or at least that portion would help.

Comment: It's not a form, just 2 select boxes. <select id="nap4" class="napkeeComponent napkeeCombobox" disabled>
</select> I'm pretty now the issue is something to do with the php as when i run it by itself it does not print the option tags, just the contents of them?

Comment: Well your ajax is also not looking like it will send what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues in your jQuery:

```
<select id="nap2" class="napkeeComponent napkeeCombobox">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="2">Three</option>
</select>
<select id="nap4" class="napkeeComponent napkeeCombobox" disabled>
</select>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#nap2").change(function(event){
        // You just get the value of selected input
        // You don't need to find anything because you've already selected it
        var selected = $(this).val();
        $('#nap4').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#nap4').empty();
        $.ajax({ 
                type: "GET",
                url: 'getbiketype.php',
                // Your creation of the data object is incorrect
                data: { name: selected },
                success:  function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    // Here just append the straight data
                    $('#nap4').append(data);
                }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```